# Splitter CreateStatic issue

Tags: c++, mfc

I have next error when I tried to create a static splitter in MainFrame class.
Error C2653: 'CMyView' : is not a class or namespace name   c:\projects\mt\mt\mainfrm.cpp   200 1   MT

I have tried to add #include "MainFrm.h" a the top of the MainFrm.cpp but it make another error about CMyDoc. How I can solve this issue?

```
    BOOL CMainFrame::OnCreateClient(LPCREATESTRUCT /*lpcs*/,
    CCreateContext* pContext)
{
    //calculate client size
    CRect cr;
    GetClientRect(&cr);

    if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateStatic(this, 1, 2))
        return FALSE;

    if (!m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 0, RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyView), CSize(cr.Width() / 2, cr.Height()), pContext) ||
        !m_wndSplitter.CreateView(0, 1, RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyView), CSize(cr.Width() / 2, cr.Height()), pContext))
    {
        m_wndSplitter.DestroyWindow();
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the header where you defined CMyView in the MainFrm.cpp file. Make sure you don't include MyView.h in MyDoc.h, and MyDoc.h in MyView.h. That would create a cyclic dependency; use forward declaration if needed, to avoid such cycles.

Comment: I have added #include "MTCDoc.h"
#include "MTCView.h" in MainFrm.cpp and it works.